# Populating HTML div using PageMethods/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

My problem is little strange. Of course I checked many examples before I write here.

I have a div element at aspx i am sending Post with AJAX to populate it

```
<script>
     function send(inputa, inputb) {

         var dataString = JSON.stringify({
             Id: inputa,
             Opt: inputb                 
         });

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "my.aspx/Myfunction",
             data: dataString,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (result) {
                 alert(result.d);
                 $("divtable").val(result.d);
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("Problem Occured");
             }
         });
     }
</script>
```

At alert I can see my response is good with no problem, but I could not send it to my div element. I tried many scripts

```
 $("divtable").val(result.d);    
 $("#divtable").val(result.d);    
 $("divtable").html(result.d);    
 $(.divtable).val(result.d);
```

and I could not success. Every searh I made I found different answers.
Can someone good at this give us the correct answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call val() on a div, because it is not an input, select, etc. And you probably should not use html() if you're not inserting markup. Try text() instead.

Also, your selector may not be correct: could you post your div HTML as well?

Comment: <div id="divtable" runat="server">
</div>

Comment: Then use $("#divtable").text(result.d). But you also need to include the ClientIDMode="Static" on your div, because you've made it a 'server element' using the 'runat' attribute. Asp.Net will automatically change its client id otherwise to use the control's hierarchy.

Comment: Good news it printed now but the problem is old data stays in page too. Because old datas id is changed asp.net it dont feels there is only one div anymore. So strange and unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("divtable").innerHTML = result.d
```

or

```
$("#divtable").html(result.d);
```

You cant use val with div, but You can use innerHtml or Jquery's html but use a valid selector like an id "#divtable" or a class ".divtable" not sure what your html looks like :)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xp3rfgbh/1/);

Comment: text() also didnt work
 $("#divtable").text(result.d);

Comment: If I dont see your html for divtable I can not know if You used an id or a class can You please show me?

I didnt say to use text anyway just html :) or innerHTML in relation if You are using JQuery or not :)

Comment: Okey good thing i found out problem, asp.net was chaing div's id. but the thing is now i can populate my div tag but old data keep staying there aswell. my problem is my div has runat=server
<div id="divtable" runat="server"> because im filling my table with sb.Builder and values from database. Now if you could help it would be so good. If they are not workıng together, shall i turn everything to javascript??

Comment: yes but first old data comes from aspx.cs and this new data is coming with javascript. But i cant clear old data before i print new one

Comment: In what Html is goin the old data?